# using shared preferences to store data inside a service?

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I have tried using the following code but i am getting errors. getSharedPreferences is undefined. Is there is other way to store string value in Intent services and access it inside an activity.

```
      SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: refer this blog its has excellent tutorial for shared preferences http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

instead of

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

getSharedPreferences() is a method of a Context object. That means you must call it within Acitivity. If you are calling it from a View subclass, you must do something like:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```